# Store source timezone in Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, timezone

In the datawarehouse we need to capture date and time value with timezone as received from source application DB. But Postgresql is converting those values into native timezone every time. Is there a way to maintain source provided timestamp with timezone value in Postgresql database as is?

E.g. from source DB if we get the timezone value as "01/20/2010 11:15:33.000000 -06:00" , want to store this value as it is in warehouse which is at different timezone. Is there any way to do that in Postgresql?

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way to store the source time zone, all timestamps with time zone are stored as UTC. You can extract the time zone and store it in a separate column, and then use a view to provide the data at the time zone you want.